# MySQL PHP way to count after a 'reset' record is inputted

Tags: php, mysql, select

I am having trouble trying to work out how to structure my query to allow me to 'reset' and only count records after there has been a reset.

Basic Structure

```
Log Table
ID | Date        | Time     | SectorID | personnumber

1  | 2020-02-10  | 13:23:00 | 23       | 66 (This is a row to be counted)
2  | 2020-02-10  | 13:28:00 | 38       | 66 (This is a row to be counted)
3  | 2020-02-10  | 13:30:00 | 5        | 66 (This is a 'reset' row) (SectorID 5 is a reset)
4  | 2020-02-10  | 13:38:00 | 12       | 66 (This is a row to be counted)
5  | 2020-02-10  | 13:42:00 | 56       | 66 (This is a row to be counted)
```

For the above, there are 2 records, then there was a reset (which is indicated by sector ID of 5), and then 2 more records (the other records can be any other number other than 5).

So I want the 'count' to return 2

The query below is what I have for counting all records without any reset function

```
SELECT
personnumber,
count(*) as occurrences
FROM log
WHERE personnumber IS NOT NULL
AND sectorid != 5
GROUP BY personnumber
HAVING count(*) > 1
ORDER BY occurrences DESC, personnumber
```

This would return

```
Personnumber | Occurrences
66           | 4
```

I hope this explains my problem sufficiently. Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks
Jon

Comment: What if there are 3 more records after that where ID 6 is another "reset", and ID 7 and 8 are records with sectorID 11 and personnumber 77?  Would your desired result only have the count of 2 for the 77?  Or would it have two for the 77 _and_ two for the 66?

Comment: not clear what should be the output if you have two records with `sectorid=5` for one and the same `personnumber`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could `JOIN` the same table by using `sectorId` and `personnumeber` in order to count all the records after this id:

```
SELECT
    l.personnumber,
    COUNT(*) as occurrences
FROM 
    `log` l
    INNER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT id, personnumber 
        FROM   `log` ll 
        WHERE  ll.sectorid = 5
    ) AS ll ON l.personnumber = ll.personnumber
WHERE 
    l.personnumber IS NOT NULL
    AND l.id > ll.id
GROUP BY l.personnumber
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY 
    occurrences DESC, 
    l.personnumber
```

Output:

```
+--------------+-------------+
| personnumber | occurrences |
+--------------+-------------+
|           66 |           2 |
+--------------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

If you need only the records after the last occurrence of sector 5 for particular `personnumber`, then you need to get the maximum id within the derived table:

```
SELECT
    l.personnumber,
    COUNT(*) as occurrences
FROM 
    `log` l
    INNER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT MAX(id) AS id, personnumber 
        FROM   `log` ll 
        WHERE  ll.sectorid = 5
        GROUP BY personnumber
    ) AS ll ON l.personnumber = ll.personnumber
WHERE 
    l.personnumber IS NOT NULL
    AND l.id > ll.id
GROUP BY l.personnumber
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY 
    occurrences DESC, 
    l.personnumber
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for that. I think that is defiantly along the right lines but are we able to compare the two on the date and time field as there is possibility for the time to be changed and the ID to be out of sync.

Comment: If `sectorid` could be changed (if I got it right), then what should be the criteria to take the next records?

Comment: The `date` and `time` field can change so `sectorid` 5 can be moved back basically so it is date, time driven rather than id

Comment: Ok, and again - if date and time become changed (but sectorId remains 5), then what should be the reliable criteria to fetch needed records?

Comment: Sorry, I am not quite understanding you here.
The personnumber will be the same (in this case we are trying to get 66)

Comment: Provided SQL actually relays on the primary ID, so even if you change the `date/time`, you will get the same result. If you need something different, then provide an additional example please.

Comment: Ahh okay, I don't want it to rely on the primary id. It is ordered on the date/time rather than the ID.
So where you have `l.id > ll.id` is it just a case of changing it so that it adds 1 to count when `l.date` and `l.time` are greater than `ll.date` and `ll.time`.
Hope I have explained that correctly

Comment: Great thanks a lot for your help. Sorry for getting confused at first